# Python: Split string by list of separators

Tags: python, regex, split, separator

In Python, I'd like to split a string using a list of separators. The separators could be either commas or semicolons. Whitespace should be removed unless it is in the middle of non-whitespace, non-separator characters, in which case it should be preserved.

Test case 1: `ABC,DEF123,GHI_JKL,MN OP`
Test case 2: `ABC;DEF123;GHI_JKL;MN OP`
Test case 3: `ABC ; DEF123,GHI_JKL ; MN OP`

Sounds like a case for regular expressions, which is fine, but if it's easier or cleaner to do it another way that would be even better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should be much faster than regex and you can pass a list of separators as you wanted:

```
def split(txt, seps):
    default_sep = seps[0]

    # we skip seps[0] because that's the default separator
    for sep in seps[1:]:
        txt = txt.replace(sep, default_sep)
    return [i.strip() for i in txt.split(default_sep)]
```

How to use it:

```
>>> split('ABC ; DEF123,GHI_JKL ; MN OP', (',', ';'))
['ABC', 'DEF123', 'GHI_JKL', 'MN OP']
```

Performance test:

```
import timeit
import re


TEST = 'ABC ; DEF123,GHI_JKL ; MN OP'
SEPS = (',', ';')


rsplit = re.compile("|".join(SEPS)).split
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: [s.strip() for s in rsplit(TEST)]))
# 1.6242462980007986

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: split(TEST, SEPS)))
# 1.3588597209964064
```

And with a much longer input string:

```
TEST = 100 * 'ABC ; DEF123,GHI_JKL ; MN OP , '

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: [s.strip() for s in rsplit(TEST)]))
# 130.67168392999884

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: split(TEST, SEPS)))
# 50.31940778599528
```

Comment: SO compacts the whitespaces, there are more than two consecutive whitespaces in the string above

Comment: Thankfully there will always be either comma or semicolons.

Comment: On my machine, the second solution I gave is even faster for short strings.

Comment: @fabrizioM if you don't want that it splits at whitespace you shouldn't call `split` with those arguments!

Comment: Instead of having default_sep be a parameter, just use one of the seps. eg: `default_sep = seps[0]` and then change the `for` line to `for sep in seps[1:]:`.

Comment: This relies on the caller knowing in advance that there's a character (e.g. "|") that can never appear in the input. This is distaster-prone.

Comment: @blah238: Very not nice. Please reconsider.

Comment: This comparison is flawed: it compiles the regex every time through the loop.  If you properly compile the regex outside of the loop (`r = re.compile(",|;")`), the regex version is faster.  It's also the clear, ordinary, flexible solution to this which everyone understands immediately, which is an even stronger argument than performance.

Comment: @blah238, @Joschua: @Glenn Maynard: On my machine: Joschua: 2.30, r=re.compile(...) in setup: 2.18, rs=re.compile(...).split in setup: 2.08. Further note: Joschua's method is O(SN) where S is the number of separators.

Answer (score 6):

Using regular expressions, try

```
[s.strip() for s in re.split(",|;", string)]
```

or

```
[t.strip() for s in string.split(",") for t in s.split(";")]
```

without.

Comment: Rather do it through string's `split()` to avoid importing `re`, e.g. `'ABC,DEF123,GHI_JKL,MN OP'.split(',|;')`

Comment: @macrog: Wouldn't this split the string at all verbatim occurrences of `",|;"`?

Comment: But if you want to split at ,;. you have to add a for-loop for every character!

Comment: @Joshua: But the question states we only want to split at `,` and `;`.  And I would use the regex version anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the above answer, with your test cases, you want to use a regular expression, and *one or more* separation characters. In your case, the separation characters seem to be ',', '|', ';' and whitespace. Whitespace in python is '\w', so the comprehension is:

```
import re
list = [s for s in re.split("[,|;\W]+", string)]
```

I cannot reply to sven's answer above, but I split on one or more of the characters inside the brackets, and don't have to use the strip() method.

Yikes, I didn't read the question correctly... Sven's answer with the strip works; mine assumes the whitespace is another separation.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> re.split('\s*,\s*|\s*;\s*', 'a , b; cdf')
['a', 'b', 'cdf']
```