# Get data between 1st and 2nd pipe in python

Tags: python, regex

This is my sample data

```
78|Indonesia|Pamela|Reid|preid25@gravatar.com|147.3.67.193
```

I want to get the result as

```
Indonesia
```

Currently I am using split on the string and accessing the value. But I want to use regex for it.

Some conditions to be aware of:
The data may be empty
The data will NOT contain pipe (|)

I want to use regex instead of split because I think regex are more efficient. The reason I want this to be as efficient as possible is because the source file is **70gb**.

**EDIT:**

This is the whole code in which I will be using this

```
def main(argv):
    mylist = set();
    input_file = open("test.txt", 'r')

    for row in input_file:
        rowsplit = row.split("|");

        if rowsplit[1] !='':
            if rowsplit[1] in mylist:
                filename= "bby_"+rowsplit[1]+".dat";
                existingFile=open(filename,'a')
                existingFile.write(row);
                existingFile.close()
            else:
                mylist.add(rowsplit[1])
                filename= "bby_"+rowsplit[1]+".dat";
                newFile = open(filename,'a')
                newFile.write(row);
                newFile.close();
        else:
            print "Empty"
    print mylist
```

I'm just confused on which of the answers I should now use :(

I just want this code to be fast. Thats it.

Comment: you could parse it line by line right then it does not matter as per by knowledge

Comment: If there is one pipe will there always be more than one or can a pipe appear anywhere?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't get what you are saying

Comment: I mean do the lines that have pipe characters always look like your input example

Comment: This is just a sample data. There are going to be some number of columns delimited by | . I am just supposed to get the data from the 2nd column and use it .

Comment: Regex is very flexible, but that flexibility comes at a cost.  As Yaroslav Admin's answer shows, using regex for this task is **much slower** than using the `str.split` method.

Comment: Side note. You will probably save **much more** time by keeping your files open all the time instead of opening and closing them in the loop for each row. As I understand you're classifying data by country, so keeping around 200-300 open files is not a big deal.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin The input data is going to be 70 gigs. That is what I am worried about. And the data I have used is what I generated online for testing. The original data might have a very long column value.

Comment: @ViChU In this case my previous note doesn't make sense.

Comment: can there be a single pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

splitting and checking the length may still be faster than a regex:

```
for line in f:
    spl = line.split("|",2)
    if len(spl) > 2:
        print(spl[1])
       ....
```

Some timings on matching and non-matching lines:

```
In [24]: s = "78|Indonesia|Pamela|Reid|preid25@gravatar.com|147.3.67.193"

In [25]: %%timeit                                                        
    spl = s.split("|",2)
    if len(spl) > 2:
        pass
   ....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 413 ns per loop

In [26]: r = re.compile(r'(?<=\|)[^|]*')

In [27]: timeit r.search(s)                                            
1000000 loops, best of 3: 452 ns per loop

In [28]: s = "78 Indonesia Pamela Reid preid25@gravatar.com 147.3.67.193"

In [29]: timeit r.search(s)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 µs per loop

In [30]: %%timeit                       
    spl = s.split("|",2)
    if len(spl) > 2:
        pass
   ....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 342 ns per loop
```

You can shave a bit more off by creating a local reference to str.split:

```
_spl = str.split
for line in f:
    spl = _spl(s,"|",2)
    if len(spl) > 2:
      .....
```

Since there are always at the same number of pipes in each line:

```
def main(argv):
    seen = set() # only use if you actually need  a set of all names
    with open("test.txt", 'r') as infile:
        r = csv.reader(infile, delimiter="|")
        for row in r:
            v = row[1]
            if v:
                filename = "bby_" + v + ".dat"
                existingFile = open(filename, 'a')
                existingFile.write(row)
                existingFile.close()
                seen.add(v)
            else:
                print "Empty"
```

if/else seems redundant as you are appending to the file regardless, if you want to keep a set of the row[1]'s for another reason you can just add to the set each time, unless you actually want a set of all the names I would remove it from the code.

Applying the same logic to split:

```
def main(argv):
    seen = set()
    with open("test.txt", 'r') as infile:
        _spl = str.split
        for row in infile:
            v = _spl(row,"|",2)[1]
            if v:
                filename = "bby_" + v + ".dat"
                existingFile = open(filename, 'a')
                existingFile.write(row)
                existingFile.close()
                seen.add(v)
            else:
                print "Empty"
```

What will cause a lot of overhead is constantly opening and writing but unless you could store all the lines in memory there is no simple way to get around it.

As far as reading goes, on a file with ten million lines just splitting twice outperforms the csv reader:

```
In [15]: with open("in.txt") as f:
   ....:     print(sum(1 for _ in f))
   ....: 
10000000

In [16]: paste
def main(argv):
    with open(argv, 'r') as infile:
        for row in infile:
            v = row.split("|", 2)[1]
            if v:
                pass
## -- End pasted text --

In [17]: paste
def main_r(argv):
    with open(argv, 'r') as infile:
        r = csv.reader(infile, delimiter="|")
        for row in r:
            if row[1]:
                pass

## -- End pasted text --

In [18]: timeit main("in.txt")
1 loops, best of 3: 3.85 s per loop

In [19]: timeit main_r("in.txt")
1 loops, best of 3: 6.62 s per loop
```

Comment: @ViChU, are there always the same number of pipes? That is going to be a big factor in what the best approach is

Comment: Yes .. Same number of pipes.

Comment: Then the split just checking `if v` is going to be the fastest approach, do you know the potential countries that will appear in the second column? if so we can probably speed the io up quite a bit

Comment: The country is just a sample data which I generated online. The original file will have a very long data in the column.

Comment: @ViChU, I presume you have no way of knowing what the values are until you run the code then?

Comment: Yes , I just realized that my if else does not make sense since I'm doing the same thing over again. I changed from list to set in the end, that made me forget that sets do not accept duplicates. I'm a bad programmer :|

Comment: @ViChU, nobody gets it right the first time ;) What is the purpose of keeping the list or the `row[1]'s`?

Comment: Yes. Actually the requirement I got was to create a script that will create separate files based on the values in the 2nd column of a pipe delimited input data. The input file is 70 gigs. This is what I was told to work on.

Comment: I have tried incorporating  imap., ifilter, and a host of other ways to do the parsing, nothing seems to come near to simply `split("|",2)`

Comment: I will pass the `row[1]'s` to the logger to show the different files being created. Also this data is fed to another system which uses it to cook the filenames and wget's them to their server.

Comment: One more thing to note : The server uses Python 2.4.3

Comment: The only issue would be using `with`, everything else bar that should work on python2.4

Answer (score 5):

Here is the performance of the *meaningful* answers on Python 3.4.3:

```
In [4]: timeit.timeit('s.split("|", 2)[1]', 's = "78|Indonesia|Pamela|Reid|preid25@gravatar.com|147.3.67.193"')
Out[4]: 0.43930888699833304

In [10]: timeit.timeit('re.search(r"^[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+)", s).group(1)', 's = "78|Indonesia|Pamela|Reid|preid25@gravatar.com|147.3.67.193"; import re')
Out[10]: 1.234878903022036

In [16]: timeit.timeit('re.search("^\d*\|(\w+?)?\|", s).group(1)', 's = "78|Indonesia|Pamela|Reid|preid25@gravatar.com|147.3.67.193"; import re')
Out[16]: 1.8305770770530216
```

If there is no pipes:

```
In [24]: timeit.timeit('s.split("|", 2)[1] if "|" in s else None', 's = "78|Indonesia|Pamela|Reid|preid25@gravatar.com|147.3.67.193"')
Out[24]: 0.494665392965544

In [25]: timeit.timeit('s.split("|", 2)[1] if "|" in s else None', 's =  ""')
Out[25]: 0.04492994397878647
```

Comment: What if there is no pipes?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Then the data file is broken, so it's acceptable if the program raises an exception. According to the OP, they just have to extract the data from the 2nd column, so it's reasonable to assume that there will always be (at least) two columns.

Comment: @AvinashRaj See added part.

Comment: There will always be pipe in the input. Only the data may be empty.

Comment: @ViChU: Yaroslav's code will work fine if the pipes are there but the 2nd column is empty: it'll just return an empty string.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin can you tell me what this does - `s.split("|", 2)[1]` I didn't get the 2 in split.

Comment: @ViChU It limits `split()` for only 2 first separator occurrences. So it will return list of 3 elements: first column, second column and the rest. It's also and optimization, especially, when you have a lot of columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find your answer at: [Python: Split string by list of separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697006/python-split-string-by-list-of-separators)

```
def split(txt, seps):
    default_sep = seps[0]

    # we skip seps[0] because that's the default seperator
    for sep in seps[1:]:
        txt = txt.replace(sep, default_sep)

    return [i.strip() for i in txt.split(default_sep)]
```

Joschua (user who answered question linked to above) tested and it was more efficient that regex.

Answer (score 0):

This one's fairly simple:  If you know the first clause will always be a number (or empty), you can anchor to the front.

```
^\d*\|(\w+?)?\|
```

This will match 0 or more numbers in the front of the line, followed by a literal `|` character, followed by clause 1, which will contain a non-greedy matched word (with no spaces), or nothing if it doesn't exist, followed by a literal `|` character.

Performance regex is about failing quickly, and non-greedy matching and anchors are crucial.

Comment: OP said clauses could be empty, so you might want `d*` for the first part

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  I assumed OP was referring to only the second clause possibly being empty.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just grab the first word using this regex.

```
re.search(r'^[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+)', S).group(1)
```

Comment: this also considers the first element.

Comment: print the first group.

Answer (score 0):

this will give you the thing between 1st and 2nd pipe:

```
 re.search(r'(?<=\|)[^|]*',s).group()
```

> re.search(pattern, string, flags=0) 
>   Scan through string looking for
>   the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a
>   match.....

Answer (score 0):

If there is always same nuber of pipes, you can use regex:

```
[^|]+(?=(?:\|[^|]+\|?){4}$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xO0cX1/1)