# Python split string ignoring \"

Tags: python, string, split

A file contains lines like this:

```
'MEASUREMENT machine.b_runs "Bit \"machine runs\" Bit"'
```

What I want is to split it into a list which is like:

```
list = ['\'MEASUREMENT', 'machine.b_runs', 'Bit \"machine runs\" Bit']
```

So that the line is split by `' '` except the words between double quotes, by ignoring `\"`

How do I do this in python?

Comment: You can split a string with a regular expression and remove the delimiters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697006/python-split-string-by-list-of-separators

Comment: is there any possiblity of your strin like `\"\\"Bit \"machine runs\" Bit"` ?

Comment: Your example string should end with a single quote. Our start with a double quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x=r'MEASUREMENT machine.b_runs "Bit \"machine runs\" Bit"'
print re.split(r'\s(?=(?:(?:[^"]|\\")*(?<!\\)"(?:[^"]|\\")*(?<!\\)")*(?:[^"]|\\")*$)',x)
```

You can try something like this.

Output:`['MEASUREMENT', 'machine.b_runs', '"Bit \\"machine runs\\" Bit"']`

Comment: Can you maybe explain, what  `r'\s(?=(?:(?:[^"]|\\")*(?<!\\)"(?:[^"]|\\")*(?<!\\)")*(?:[^"]|\\")*$)' ` does?

Comment: @Itaipu Its a lookahead stating find a space which has a pair of " ahead of it.    The " should not have \ before it