# How to remove text within parentheses from Python string?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to remove parentheses and the text that resides in these parentheses, as well as hyphen characters. Some string examples look like the following:
`example = 'Year 1.2 Q4.1 (Section 1.5 Report (#222))'`
`example2 = 'Year 2-7 Q4.8 - Data markets and phases' ##there are two hyphens`

I would like the results to be:

```
example = 'Year 1.2 Q4.1'  
example2 = 'Year 2-7 Q4.8'
```

How can I remove text residing within or following parentheses and special characters? I could only find `str.strip()` method. I am new to Python, so any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are many ways. You should have a look at doing it with regex. I tagged it with regex and soon the regex sharks will be here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Split string by list of separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697006/python-split-string-by-list-of-separators)

Comment: @AntonvBR lol.  The regex sharks are circling the waters

Answer (score 6):

You may use below regex to get the desired result:

```
"\(.*\)|\s-\s.*"
#   ^     ^  Pattern 2: everything followed by space, '-' hyphen, space
#   ^   Pattern 1: everything within brackets (....)
```

Sample run:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_regex = "\(.*\)|\s-\s.*"

>>> example = 'Year 1.2 Q4.1 (Section 1.5 Report (#222))'
>>> example2 = 'Year 2-7 Q4.8 - Data markets and phases'

>>> re.sub(my_regex, "", example)
'Year 1.2 Q4.1'
>>> re.sub(my_regex, "", example2)
'Year 2-7 Q4.8'
```

Here I am using [**`re.sub(pattern, repl, string, ...)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) which as the document says:

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
>   occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement *repl*. If the
>   pattern isn’t found, *string* is returned unchanged. *repl* can be a
>   string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it
>   are processed.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using a * and a throwaway variable.

```
example = 'Year 1.2 Q4.1 (Section 1.5 Report (#222))'
display,*_ = example.split('(')
print(display)

example2 = 'Year 2-7 Q4.8 - Data markets and phases' ##there are two hyphens
part_1,part_2,*_ = example2.split('-')
display = part_1 + '-'+ part_2
print(display)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this , you will need little data cleaning after you fetch result to make it as your desired output:

```
import re
data=[]
pattern=r'\(.+\)|\s\-.+'
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match=re.search(pattern,line)
        data.append(line.replace(match.group(),'').strip())

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example without regex (just to show you have good regex can be):

The code adds strings until a string starts with `Q`:

```
example = 'Year 1.2 Q4.1 (Section 1.5 Report (#222))'

def clean_string(s):
    for item in s.split():
        yield item
        if item.startswith('Q'):
            break

print(' '.join(clean_string(example)))
```