# How to remove parentheses and all data within using Python3

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to remove parenthesis and all data within using Python 3.

I've looked into several different threads, including here:

[How to remove parentheses and all data within using Pandas/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894525/how-to-remove-parentheses-and-all-data-within-using-pandas-python)

After finally getting:

```
re.sub(r"\(.*\)|\s-\s.*", r"", str1)
```

to run without errors, it didn't remove the content from the str1 string.

Then I tried this approach:

[How to remove text within parentheses from Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997659/how-to-remove-text-within-parentheses-from-python-string)

to remove the parenthesis and contents from the file before reading it in and storing to str1 - 
but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "sum_all.py", line 27, in <module>
    data.append(line.replace(match.group(),'').strip())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Here is the code, I'm obviously new at this and appreciate any help!!

```
# Python3 program to calculate sum of 
# all numbers present in a str1ing 
# containing alphanumeric characters 

# Function to calculate sum of all 
# numbers present in a str1ing 
# containing alphanumeric characters 
import re
import math
import pyperclip
import pandas
def find_sum(str1): 
    # Regular Expression that matches digits in between a string 
    return sum(map(int,re.findall('\d+',str1))) 

def find_sum2(str2): 
    # Regular Expression that matches digits where hr follows short for hours 
    return sum(map(int,re.findall('(\d+)hr',str1)))

str2=0

# Regular Expression 
data=[]
pattern=r'\(.+\)|\s\-.+'
with open('project.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match=re.search(pattern,line)
        data.append(line.replace(match.group(),'').strip())

print(data)

# input alphanumeric str1ing 
with open ("project.txt", "r") as myfile:
    str1=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')


# Regular Expression that removes (*) and Normalizes White Space - didn't work
#re.sub(r"\(.*\)|\s-\s.*", r"", str1)

# Regular Expression that removes (*) - didn't work
#re.sub(r"\(.*\)", r"", str1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. `r"\((.*?)\)"`

The `\(` and `\)` say we want to target the actual parenthesis.

Then the parenthesis around the expression `(.*?)` say that we want to group what is inside.

Finally the `.*?` means that we want any character `.` and any repetition  of that character `*?`.

```
s = "start (inside) this is in between (inside) end"
res = re.sub(r"\((.*?)\)", "", s)
print(res)
```

prints

```
'start  this is in between  end'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi I tried that and it's not working when I try it.  I get: "start (inside) this is in between (inside) end"  I'm running a file inside mac terminal.

Comment: It works brilliantly when I do (thanks so much):                                                                                        s = "start (inside) this is in between (inside) end"
s = re.sub(r"\((.*?)\)", "", s)

Comment: Strings are immutable objects in python [link](http://net-informations.com/python/iq/immutable.htm). So the function `re.sub(..., s)` can't change the value of `s` directly.  That is why when you are expecting a string from a function it is very usual to get it as a return value. Such as `s2=re.seb(...., s)`