# Python - .split(), - two arguments

Tags: python

I need to make a modification on a python code.

This code scrapes information from a .csv file, to finally integrate it in a new .csv file, in a different structure.

In one of the columns of the source files, I have a value (string), which is in 99% of the time formed this way: 'block1 block2 block3'.

Block2 always ends with the value 'm' 99% of the time.

example: 'R2 180m RFT'.

By browsing the source dataset, I realized that in 1% of the cases, the block2 can end with 'M'.

As I need all the values after the 'm' or 'M' value, I'm a bit stuck.

I used the .split() function, like this in my :

```
'Newcolumn': getattr(row_unique_ids, 'COLUMNINTHEDATASET').split ('m') [1],
```

By doing so, my script falls in error, because it falls on a value of this style :
R2 180**M** AST'.

So I would like to know how to integrate an additional argument, which would allow me to make the split work well if the script falls on 'm' or 'M'.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there another pattern you can identify, like for instance there is always a number before m or M, so if it ends on a number you can split there?

Comment: You can convert the string to lower case before applying the split, did you try that?

Comment: why not split at space and just get the last element of resulting list?

Comment: If you *must* have multiple characters, `re.split` can accommodate this.

Comment: can't you just split with ' '(space) and take the last word?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Split string by list of separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697006/python-split-string-by-list-of-separators)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to

```py
s = getattr(row_unique_ids, 'COLUMNINTHEDATASET')
s = s.lower()
s.split('m')[1]
```

But that will mess up your casing. If you want to preserve casing,
another solution is to do:

```py
x = ''
s = getattr(row_unique_ids, 'COLUMNINTHEDATASET')
for c in s:
  if c == 'M'
    x += 'm'
  x += c
x.split('m')[1]
```

Comment: The first solution is just lowercasing the attribute name which will almost certainly not exist.

Comment: the second solution will not work because when you split with 'm' ssome of the line will stay with just 1 item in list and than you will get 'list index out of range'

Comment: steel not work, after your loop the line will look like ''R2 180mM RFT'. test your solustion before you submit them

Comment: yep there was a syntax error with lowercasing the attribute name, the general idea should still work. This works now.

Answer (score 0):

**One way to do multi-arguments split is, in general:**

```
import re

string = "this is 3an infamous String4that I need to s?plit in an infamou.s way"

#Preserve the original char
print (re.sub(r"([0-9]|[?.]|[A-Z])",r'\1'+"DELIMITER",string).split('DELIMITER'))

#Discard the original char
print (re.sub(r"([0-9]|[?.]|[A-Z])","DELIMITER",string).split('DELIMITER'))
```

Output:

```
['this is 3', 'an infamous S', 'tring4', 'that I', ' need to s?', 'plit in an infamou.', 's way']
['this is ', 'an infamous ', 'tring', 'that ', ' need to s', 'plit in an infamou', 's way']
```

**In your context:**

```
import re

string = "R2 180m RFT R2 180M RFT"

print (re.sub(r"\b([0-9]+)[mM]\b",r'\1'+"M",string).split('M'))
#print (re.sub(r"\b([0-9]+)[mM]\b",r'\1'+"M",getattr(row_unique_ids, 'COLUMNINTHEDATASET')).split('M'))
```

Output:

```
['R2 180', ' RFT R2 180', ' RFT']
```

It will split on `m` and `M` if those are preceded by a number.

Comment: great answer, this is definitely more detailed, upvoted!

Comment: Thank you :). That may not look good practice tho, but when you missed those good practices in preparing data, it helps!

Comment: Whyyyy... would you do a regex replace and then a string split when you could do a regex split and be done with it? `re.split('[mM]', 'R2 180m RFT')`

Comment: also `([0-9]|[?.]|[A-Z])` is a needlessly complicated way of writing `([0-9?.A-Z])`

Comment: Yes, but that's to highlight that there are 3 different kinds of delimiters... The novice may understand easier in that form.  Also re.split() does not allow to capture groups as far I know. So if you want to preserve the delimiter you can't. Finally, I tend to do that cause I chain re.sub on blocks of text and split at the end. But that's my personal pipeline.

Comment: Normal string split also does not preserve the delimiter (and the OP did not want to keep the delimiter, either). If you're introducing the `re` package and regex then you've just made the whole thing *an order or magnitude* more complex for the OP, sparing them the `re.split()` will not make things easier. Not to mention that a solution on `re.split()` is shorter and easier to follow than what you're proposing.

Comment: So I would recommend you to edit your own post and add this solution. This would not be a needlessly complicated task and it would show people how more efficient/understandable/OP-friendly your mind/skills can be. Thanks for pointing out the right way of doing things!

Comment: I'm trying to improve on your answer here. There is no need to get snappy.